# Ansible to install Sublime Text editor in Linux

Tags: bash, ubuntu, ansible

I am trying to install Sublime Text (on Ubuntu) using Ansible. Here is the basic Ansible playbook I am trying to use for accomplishing this, based on:

1. bash commands [here](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/linux_repositories.html#apt) to install Sublime Text
2. Ansible docs [apt-repository](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/apt_repository_module.html#examples) and [apt-key](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/apt_key_module.html#examples)

   ```
   ---
   - hosts: all
   vars:
     - my_repos:
         - ppa: https://download.sublimetext.com/
         - ppa: [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/
     - my_pkgs:
         - sublime-text
         - google-chrome-stable

   tasks:
     - Install GPG key
       name: install GPG key for SubLimeText
       ???????

     - name: Add specified repositories into sources list using specified filename
       apt_repository: repo=deb {{ item }} stable main
                       state=present
                       filename='{{ item }}'
       with_items:
         - my_repos

     - name: Install packages
       apt: state=installed pkg={{ item }}
       with_items:
         - my_pkgs
   ```

The first task is to install the GPG key for SublimeText (per the 1st link above). I read the Ansible docs [here](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/apt_key_module.html#examples), but I do not know how to translate that into the SublimeText case.

**Questions:**

1. In the SublimeText instructions, step 1: a direct link to the GPG key is specified. They say:

   `Install the GPG key: https://download.sublimetext.com/sublimehq-pub.gpg`

   but how do I add this using the Ansible `apt_key` module?
2. In step 2: Does the task to use `apt_repository` correspond to the bash command `echo "deb https://download.sublimetext.com/ apt/stable/" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sublime-text.list`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
---
- hosts: all
  vars:
    - my_pkgs:
      - sublime-text
      - google-chrome-stable

  tasks:
  - name: Install GPG key for SubLimeText
    apt_key:
      url: https://download.sublimetext.com/sublimehq-pub.gpg
      state: present

  - name: Add specified repositories into sources list using specified filename
    apt_repository:
      repo: deb {{ item.repo }} {{ item.add }}
      state: present
      filename: "{{ item.file }}"
    with_items:
      - repo: https://download.sublimetext.com/
        add: apt/stable/
        file: sublime
      - repo: '[arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/'
        add: stable main
        file: google-chrome

  - name: Install packages
    apt:
      state: installed
      pkg: "{{ item }}"
      update_cache: yes
    with_items:
      - "{{ my_pkgs }}"
```

Comment: Why do you have quotes here: `with_items:  - "{{ my_pkgs }}"`? Since `{{ my_pkgs }}` does not follow `:`, is `with_items: - {{ my_pkgs }}` acceptable?

Comment: Also, is `with_items: - {{ my_pkgs }}` acceptable as `with_items: - my_pkgs` on its own, withourt `{{}}`?

Comment: 1. Always quote template expression brackets when they
start a value.

Comment: 2. In case of `- my_pkgs` without `{{ }}`, it tries to install package with name `my_pkgs`.

Comment: Many thanks again! Answered the OP.  No further questions.

Comment: Is there any need for `sudo: yes` in any of this?

Comment: `state: installed` is not available - use: `state: present` (default)

Answer (score 2):

For Fedora 32, the following works as part of my main.yaml. Of course, remove the ... and edit to your needs :-)

```
- hosts: fedora
  become: true
  tasks:
...
  - name: Add Sublime repository
    yum_repository:
      name: sublime-text
      description: Sublime Text x86_64 - stable
      baseurl: https://download.sublimetext.com/rpm/stable/x86_64
      enabled: yes
      gpgcheck: yes
  - name: Add Sublime Text
    dnf:
      name: sublime-text
      state: present
...
```